# How to use Dart with Webstorm 6 on Windows (running Codelab from Google IO 2013)

Tags: dart, webstorm, dart-webui, dart-editor

I searched for but didn't find any other posts remotely related to my question. Essentially, I'm attempting to follow the Dart Codelab from Google IO 2013 which I found here: http://goo.gl/4E21M

I'm attempting to use the Dart plugin in Webstorm 6 which I setup using the directions here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/12/dart-support-in-webstorm-6/

Lastly, I'm doing this on Windows 8.

My build.dart is:

```
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  var args = new List.from(new Options().arguments);
  build(new Options().arguments, ['web/index.html'])
    .then((_) => print('Build finished!'));
}
```

My pubspec.yaml is:

```
name: writer
version: 0.0.1
author: Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>
description: This is the finished version of the application built in the Google I/O 2013 Dart Codelab.
homepage: https://github.com/dart-lang/io-2013-dart-codelab
dependencies:
  intl: any
  web_ui: any
```

Yet, when I attempt to run the step 1 code, I see in my Event Log: Error running Test: build.dart: Missing library statement in build.dart.

So that seems straight-forward enough...except I can't figure out which library statement should be there that isn't... the only line of code I removed was:

```
#!/usr/bin/env dart
```

Because I'm attempting to run this on Windows, and that is for a UNIX environment.

Any thoughts? I really appreciate any assistance you can provide getting up and running with this Codelab in Webstorm (which is LIGHT YEARS more refined then the default Dart Editor). In other words, I FAR prefer Webstorm--if I can get things up and running in it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: They may just want a `library build;` at the top of the file, though as I don't have Webstorm I can't say for sure.

Comment: which version of Dart SDK are you using? you can run `dart --version` to find out.

Comment: @PixelElephant, that seems to have helped. At least I don't get the error anymore. Now I just need to figure out how to actually, uh, "run" the index.html file. All I see when I "debug" it is an error page (webpage is not found) in Chromium. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Abe - build.dart outputs the 'built' html file in web\out\index.html - you can try running that one in Dartium.  Don't have Dartium?  You'll need to run the ...bootstrap.dart through dart2js first.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic, I'm running 0.5.9.0_r22879.

Comment: @ChrisBuckett, yep. There it is, and it worked! Fantastic. Thank you for your help! Is there more documentation somewhere I can read more about this (i.e., where certain files go and why?)? Thank you again for your help. Now I can happily Dart in Webstorm!

Comment: This one will probably explain what's going on in the background: http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/tools.html and this step in the tutorial has some diagrams and more explanation: http://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/web-ui/

Comment: @ChrisBuckett Awesome. I'll dig in to those links. And thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @ChrisBuckett and @PixelElephant my question was answered. In order to get the Codelab from Google IO 2013, Step 1, to run I had to include "library build;" at the top of my build.dart file. In order to see the post-build output, I had to look in the /out folder and "run" the index.html file in Chromium.

This combination worked.

My fixed build.dart file:

```
library build;

import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  var args = new List.from(new Options().arguments);
  build(args, ['web/index.html'])
    .then((_) => print('Build finished!'));
}
```